# syntax error: unexpected name, expecting semicolon or newline

Tags: go

I don't understand why my code has syntax error.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func ping(curl_out string) endtime int64 {
    try_curl := exec.Command("curl", "localhost:8500/v1/catalog/nodes")
    try_curl_out := try_curl.Output()
    for try_curl_out == curl_out {
        try_curl := exec.Command("curl", "localhost:8500/v1/catalog/nodes")
        try_curl_out := try_curl.Output()
    }
    endtime := time.Now().Unix()
    return endtime
}

func main() {
    run_container := exec.Command("docker", "run", "-p", "8400:8400", "-p", "8500:8500", "-p", "8600:53/udp", "-h", "node1", "progrium/consul", "-server", "-bootstrap")
    container_id, err := run_container.Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    run_curl := exec.Command("curl", "localhost:8500/v1/catalog/nodes")
    curl_out, err := run_curl.Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    endtime := go ping(string(curl_out))
    container_id, err = exec.Command("docker", "stop", container_id)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    startime := time.Now().Unix()
    fmt.Println("delay is", endtime-startime)
}

# command-line-arguments
./main.go:9: syntax error: unexpected name, expecting semicolon or newline
./main.go:11: non-declaration statement outside function body
./main.go:15: non-declaration statement outside function body
./main.go:16: non-declaration statement outside function body
./main.go:17: non-declaration statement outside function body
./main.go:18: syntax error: unexpected }
```

This code calculates time between docker start and stop.
I use routine to return end time.

```
endtime := go ping(string(curl_out))
```

I think it's wrong. How can I use keyword go?

In Go, Do I decelerate statement outside function body?

Comment: "decelerate statement outside function body"?

Answer (score 3):

There's 2 primary issues (and many unrelated).

First, you need to parenthesize named return parameters

```
func ping(curl_out string) (endtime int64) {
```

Second, you can't assign the return value of a goroutine. It's executed asynchronously in an entirely new context. Use a channel to communicate between goroutines

You could declare the ping function like:

```
func ping(curl_out string, endtime chan<- int64) {
```

And then pass in a channel on which to receive the value

```
ch := make(chan int64)
go ping(string(curl_out), ch)
endtime <- ch
```

(Though there is no point in this case to using a goroutine, since you want the value synchronously)

Answer (score 1):

In line 9:

Add parenthesis

```
func ping(curl_out string) (endtime int64) {
```

or remove return value name:

```
func ping(curl_out string) int64 {
```

And you're right about the use of `go` keyword to create a goroutine, you can't assign that to a return value, just remove the `go` keyword and assign the value directly.

Also (style)  go variables are in camelCase so you should change your variables from `run_container`  to either `runContainer`  or better just `container` or even better just `c`, same goes for `run_curl` it could be `curl`

Here's an slightly enhanced version of your code ( without really knowing what it does)

http://play.golang.org/p/3Y7TPip5kP

Comment: I want to calculate time.

starttiem  = service stop in consul
endtime = this service don't parse.